# error in finding the the symbol readline and package could not be found

Tags: java

the code , unable to understand why we have errors everything looks fine . please help

```
import java.io.*;
public class ReadKeyboard3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        System.out.print("Enter marks for English: ");
        String EnglishMarks = scanner.readline();
        int English = Integer.parseInt(EnglishMarks);

        System.out.print("Enter marks for Maths: ");
        String MathsMarks = in.readLine();
        int Maths = Integer.parseInt(MathsMarks);

        System.out.print("Enter marks for Science: ");
        String ScienceMarks = in.readLine();
        int Science = Integer.parseInt(ScienceMarks);

        float avg = (English + Maths + Science)/3;
        system.out.println("Average of all 3 subjects:" +avg);
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
ReadKeyboard3.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        String EnglishMarks = in.readline();
                                ^
  symbol:   method readline()
  location: variable in of type BufferedReader
ReadKeyboard3.java:22: error: package system does not exist
        system.out.println("Average of all 3 subjects:" +avg);
```

Can anyone help me in understanding the errors

Comment: It's readLine, not readline

Comment: Java is ***case-sensitive***. `System` (with capital `S`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual function you are trying to call is `readLine()` (not `readline()`). Also in line 22, use `System` instead of `system` (as Java is case sensitive as mentioned in comments) Also for using `Scanner`, you need to import `java.util.Scanner`.